# grsync does not reproduce quotation marks in rsync command, so never asks for password

Tags: server, ssh, backup, rsync

When running grsync to transfer local files to a remote server, the program simply sits there doing nothing.  Unfortunately it never asks me for the remote system password.

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.  grsync is 1.2.6.

When rsync is run from the prompt (by using grsync's alt-r "rsync command line", and copying the indicated command to the prompt in a terminal window), the instant error displayed (ie, no timing out) is:

```
ssh: connect to host remotehost-name port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
```

What is odd about this, is that I did not direct rsync to use port 22.  In fact, here is my grsync command:

```
rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -z -s -e ssh -p 7822 --exclude .* /local-path/local-directory/ login@remote-server:path/directory
```

To my knowledge, rsync ought to be using port 7822, as indicated in the command. Examining further, I realize that grsync has not produced the rsync command correctly.  According to the specifics of how I set up grsync, it ought to produce a command that includes **quotation marks**, like this:

```
rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -z -s -e "ssh -p 7822" --exclude ".*" /local-path/local-directory/ login@remote-server:path/directory
```

This command, when run at the prompt, does result in a password request.

Why doesn't grsync include the quotation marks?  In grsync's "advanced options" tab, I have included the quotation marks!  There, I have written this:

```
-e "ssh -p 7822" --exclude ".*"
```

What is the problem?  How can this be corrected?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I find this: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-become-an-rsync-power-user-with-grsync/ which states that Protocol and port number, must be written in the "Additional options" text box of the Advanced options panel, exactly in this way:
-e \"ssh -p PORTNUMBER\"

If you forget to escape the double quotes, Grsync won't pass them correctly to rsync, and that program will fail.                                  This was surprising as I don't need to do that in Linux Mint, nor Lubuntu.  I tried adding the \ to the quotes, but grsync crashed.

Comment: Can this be in any way related? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grsync/+bug/1789012